# My phone (Google) thinks I live in a town that doesn't exist

Tags: google, 7.0-nougat, gps-tracking, location-services

I live in a town called "Rock Rapids, Iowa." It happens to be partially in Rock Township and partially in Riverside Township of Lyon County, Iowa.

But when I ask for my weather, it says I'm in "Rock ee-uh," and displays my location as "Rock, IA" I'm sure the voice is trying to pronounce the state abbreviation, which is stupid, but is another issue.

The weather is always right, and if I ask it for the weather in Rock Rapids, it's always identical to this mythical "Rock, IA" place, so it's more of an annoyance than anything. But why does it come up like that, and is there any way that I (or Google) can fix this?

I have a Galaxy 6, SM-G920V, running Android 7.0 if it makes any difference.

Comment: It could be (stupidly) going off the township name.  Google does this for me all time, lists my location as one of the nearby townships even though I'm in the middle of the city I live in and don't even know the township names.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed recently that both my husband's M9 and my M10 started displaying Brooking Township instead of Raytown. I'm close the Kansas City city limits and I share a zip code with that city so I'm accustomed to having the wrong city display on occasion. However, I did some research and residents of a small area of Raytown named their area Brookings Township. When the city was finally recognized as a city, the official name was set to Raytown. I live on the opposite side of the city with respect to the area that was once known as Brookings Township. I found a US website with all the information about US towns lists and the township was archived as soon as it was recorded for historical purposes. I did a quick poll via the NextDoor app and everyone that has responded verified the same issue began within the last month, for various device models and service carriers. It feels like a purposeful change to jack with us or something. Or it is just an interesting weirdly targeted defect in some part of the software.